# Can someone help define what this regex does?

Tags: regex

I'm still learning regex and was hoping someone could tell me what this regex does exactly. Thank you.

```
\d{8,9}0101\d{3}
```

Comment: You can easily get this explained with: http://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

Breaking it apart:

```
\d{8,9}
```

That means either eight or nine digits (`0-9`).

```
0101
```

That means the literal string `0101`

```
\d{3}
```

That means precisely three number digits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm) to Know more.
Youre regex means

- 1.Any digit of 8 or 9 repetation
- 2 then 0101
- 3 then any digit of exact 3 repetation

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to start from some source where theory could be found, later on using some tools where you can interactively check how this knowledge can be applied.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html <- This site contains information about POSIX standard for regular expressions.

Personally for testing matching I use rubular.com, but it references ruby's implementation of regexps. So it also depends on what regexp implementation you use.

In your case it is simple to answer and there should be no difference between different regexp implementations, though.

Answer (score 1):

(A) \d{8,9} - a digit (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) repeated minimum 8 to maximum 9 times

(B) 0101 -  literal string 0101

(C) \d{3} - 3 then any digit of exact 3 repetation

regex does = A + B + C

Answer (score 0):

This finds 8 or 9 digits (numbers 0-9), followed by `0101` followed by exactly three digits...

(You should have been able to figure that out by searching!)

Answer (score 0):

**Autopsy**:

- `\d{8,9}` - *a digit (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) repeated 8 to 9 times*
- `0101` - *a literal string of the characters `0101`*
- `\d{3}` - *a digit (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) repeated exactly 3 times*

**Note**: *repeated* doesn't mean "the same character" but anything in the match. That means that "repeated exactly 3 times" for `\d` could be `111`, `123`, `989` etc.

Comment: I think "repeated" is slightly misleading. `571` matches as well as `555`.

Comment: @lonesomeday Good call - I've added a note for it.